Auto-playing Video in Inline Mode on Mobile Browsers Instead of Full-Screen
I'm experiencing an issue where a video on my website, meant to auto-play inline, instead launches in full-screen mode on all mobile browsers. This behavior persists despite correctly implementing the playsinline and webkit-playsinline attributes in my HTML code. Here’s the code snippet for reference:
<video poster="URL_TO_IMAGE" autoplay loop muted controls width="100%" height="auto" webkit-playsinline playsinline>
    <source src="URL_TO_VIDEO" type="video/webm" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


UPDATE:
Ok, i see this working only on Android devices - I checked this on Android emulators. But still not working correctly on iOS devices.
The video is meant to play automatically in the space where it is embedded on the webpage, not take over the full screen. I'm looking for any insights or solutions to ensure the video plays inline as intended. I'll attach a screenshot showing the unwanted full-screen mode. Thanks in advance for your help!
website:
https://med-lek.pl/kolagen-max/?sklep=true

Checked the URL, and there's only one <video> element, and it does not have playsinline attributes. Used your code in a CodePen, and the video correctly autoplayed inline.

I managed to resolve the issue by using a different approach in WPBakery. Instead of using the default video block which was filtering out the playsinline attribute, I added the video code using an HTML block which allowed me to retain all attributes. This change successfully enabled the video to play inline on mobile browsers without defaulting to full screen. Thank you for all the suggestions and help! Thanks Caleb :)
